# Seeking help understanding steps in a proof, in "Convergence of probability measures by P.Billingsley".

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

**To not waste anyones time: this question is directed at people who either have the mentioned book in their possesion, or have at some point read it.**

I am reading through Patrick Billingsley's book: "Convergence of probability measures" (1999), and have encountered steps in the proof of ***Theorem 19.1*** which i cant seem to follow.

The proof can be read here from google books (press on the second box from the top): http://books.google.dk/books?id=6ItqtwaWZZQC&pg=RA1-PR48&hl=da&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=7#v=onepage&q=Theorem%2019.1&f=false

**1)**

In the final steps of the proof we writes: By theorem 16.7 it is enough to show that
$$
||Y^n-X^n||_m=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\max_{k\leq mn}|\theta_k -\theta_0| \stackrel{wk}{\to}_n 0
$$
*which i think is a typo, shouldn't he make a reference to Theorem 16.1 (which is about when we have convergence in $D_\infty$ ) and thereafter say that it follows from Theorem 3.1?*

**2)**

Anyways to prove the above convergence he writes that since
$$
E\theta_0^2 < \infty \implies \sum_n P(\theta_n^2/n \geq \varepsilon)=\sum_nP(\theta_0^2 \geq n\varepsilon)<\infty \implies \theta_n^2 /n \to_n 0 \text{ P-a.s.}
$$
where the last implication follows from Borel-Cantelli. But
$$
\frac{1}{n}\max_{k\leq mn} \theta_n^2 \leq \left(\max_{k\leq n_0}\theta_k^2/n \right) \lor \left(\sup_{k>n_0 }\theta_k^2/k \right)
$$
which implies the weak convergence in 1).

*There are several things in the above which i cant seem to reproduce. Firstly i cant see how the sum converges when assuming that $E\theta_0^2 < \infty$. Secondly i dont know how to prove the inequality or how to use the former almost sure convergence in order to conclude that the RHS of the inequality converges a.s. to 0.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to show the weak convergence towards 0 in 1)**

Note that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{t\leq m} |X^n_t-Y^n_t| &= \sup_{t\leq m} \left|\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor nt \rfloor} \xi_k-
\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor nt \rfloor} \eta_k\right| \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \sup_{t\leq m} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor nt \rfloor} \xi_k-
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor nt \rfloor} \xi_k + \delta_k - \delta_{k-1}\right| \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \sup_{t\leq m} \left|\delta_{\lfloor nt \rfloor }-\delta_0\right| \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \max_{k \leq mn} \left|\delta_{k}-\delta_0\right| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \max_{k \leq mn} |\delta_{k}|+ \underbrace{\frac{\left|\delta_0\right|}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}}_{\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}_n 0}
\end{align*}
so we are done if we can show that $\frac{1}{n} \max_{k \leq mn} \delta_{k}^2\to_n 0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ almost surely. Note that for $n\to\infty$ then $nm\to\infty$ and
$$
\frac{1}{n} \max_{k \leq mn} =m \frac{1}{mn}\max_{k \leq mn} 
$$ 
so it suffices to show that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \max_{k \leq n} \delta_{k}^2 \stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}_n 0.
$$
We see that for any $\epsilon>0$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P( \delta_n^2 /n \geq \epsilon ) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P( \delta_n^2 \geq n\epsilon ) \\
\text{\{Stationarity\}}\to&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P( \delta_0^2 \geq n\epsilon ) \\
\text{\{Draw\}}\to &\leq \int_0^\infty P( \delta_0^2 \geq t\epsilon ) dt \\
 &= \int_0^\infty P( \delta_0^2/\epsilon \geq t ) dt \\
&= E(\delta_0^2/\epsilon)<\infty
\end{align*}
Thus by Borel-Cantelli we get that $$\frac{\delta_n^2}{n}\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}_n 0.$$
Fix $\omega$ in the almost sure set, where the above converges. Fix $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and then fix $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N_1 \in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\frac{\delta_k^2}{k} <\epsilon \quad \quad \text{for } n \geq N_1
$$
then choose $N_2\geq N_1$ such that 
$$
\frac{\max_{k\leq N_1}\delta_k^2}{n} < \epsilon\quad \quad \text{for } n \geq N_2
$$ 
then we get that
$$
\frac{\max_{k\leq n}\delta_k^2}{n} = \frac{\max_{k\leq N_1}\delta_k^2}{n}+ \underbrace{\frac{\max_{N_1+1\leq k\leq n}\delta_k^2}{n}}_{\exists k'>N_1 \, s.t. \downarrow \leq \delta_{k'}/k'} < \epsilon + \frac{\delta_{k'}}{k'} < 2\epsilon \quad \quad \text{for } n \geq N_2
$$
which shows that $\sup_{t\leq m} |X^n_t-Y^n_t|\to_n 0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ almost surely.

**I was not able to show that this implies that (I can't seem to use the theorem he refereed to)**
$$
X^n \stackrel{w.k.}{\rightarrow}_n W
$$
in $\mathcal{D}([0,\infty)$.

**If anyone is able to show this I would be very grateful.**